# Can clouds increase the level of UV-A radiations received on the earth surface? If so, by how much, and in which condition(s)?

Tags: clouds, sun, uv-light

The [American Scientist article](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/sunshine-on-a-cloudy-day) nicely explains that clouds sometimes increase the level of UV radiations received on the earth surface. However, all the papers they cite focused on UV-B radiations. Can clouds increase the level of UV-A radiations received on the earth surface? If so, by how much, and in which condition(s)?

---

More details from the American Scientist article:

> - According to Sabburg, "In our latest research [soon to appear in the Journal of Atmospheric Research], we use new equipment and refine our methodology, and the **highest UVI [an index of skin reddening] enhancement we found was 25 percent**." But those values are with respect to  expected clear-sky UV. Compared with the level of attenuation usually seen when clouds are present, such measurements can actually be 50 to 75 percent higher than predicted, says Sabburg.
> - Just how common is cloud enhancement? The various studies have found that between **1.4 and 8 percent of all measurements show cloud enhancement compared with clear-sky values, depending on geographic location, but as many as 25 percent of those made on partly cloudy days may show it. Most often the enhancement lasts for 10 minutes** or less—not a concern for the sun worshiper—but it has been known to persist for an hour.

Answer (score 2):

I found one study from 2001 {1}:

> It  was  also  determined  that  for  a  fulltime  outdoor  worker,  **the  additional  UVA  exposure  could  approach  approximately  that  of  one  third  of  a  full  winter’s  day**.  For  indoor  workers  with  an  outside  lunch  break  of  noon  to  1  pm,  the  additional  UVA  exposure  was  on  average  6.9  kJ m$^{-2}$ over three cloud enhanced days. To the authors’ knowledge this is the **first paper to present some evidence of cloud enhanced UVA human exposure**.

The paper doesn't explain the mechanism causing the UV-A increase.

---

References:

- {1} Sabburg, J. and Parisi, Alfio and Wong, J. C. F. (2001). Effect of cloud on UVA and exposure to humans. Photochemistry and Photobiology, 74 (3), 412-416. ISSN 0031-8655. [[GScholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C48&q=Sabburg%2C+J.+and+Parisi%2C+Alfio+and+Wong%2C+J.+C.+F.+%282001%29.+Effect+of+cloud+on+UVA+and+exposure+to+humans.+Photochemistry+and+Photobiology%2C+74+%283%29%2C+412-416.+ISSN+0031-8655.+A&btnG=)] [[PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.563.2942&rep=rep1&type=pdf)]